# Golang: Assigning a value to struct member that is a pointer

Tags: pointers, go, struct

I'm trying to assign a value to a struct member that is a pointer, but it gives "panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference" at runtime...

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

// Test
type stctTest struct {
    blTest *bool
}

func main() {

    var strctTest stctTest
    *strctTest.blTest = false

    fmt.Println("Test is " + strconv.FormatBool(*strctTest.blTest))

}
```

The runtime error seems to come from the assignment of the value with *strctTest.blTest = false , but why? How do I set it to false?

Comment: Here is a nice explanation of pointers in Go: https://dave.cheney.net/2017/04/26/understand-go-pointers-in-less-than-800-words-or-your-money-back

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Why is it an error? Because a pointer only points. It doesn't create anything to point *AT*. You need to do that.

How to set it to false? This all depends on *WHY* you made it a pointer.

Is every copy of this supposed to point to the same bool? Then it should be allocated some space in a creation function.

```
func NewStruct() *strctTest {
    bl := true
    return &strctTest{
        blTest: &bl,
     }
}
```

Is the user supposed to point it at a boolean of his own? Then it should be set manually when creating the object.

```
func main() {
    myBool := false
    stctTest := strctTest{
        blTest: &myBool
    }

    fmt.Println("Test is " + strconv.FormatBool(*strctTest.blTest))

}
```

Comment: My attempt to try the first method gave a compiler error ("invalid pointer type *bool for composite literal") but the second method worked for my purposes. Thank you!

Comment: @BartSilverstrim Ah well I didn't test it. I guess I should have.

Comment: @BartSilverstrim I fixed my first example.

Answer (score 2):

Another way you can think of it is the zero value of a boolean is false.

This is not as clear but another way to do it.

https://play.golang.org/p/REbnJumcFi

I would recommend a `New()` func that returns a reference to a initialized struct type.

Comment: This didn't really answer the OP's question. He asked how to assign a value to a bool, not how to make a new memory allocation. In your example you should add how to assign a value to it. See https://play.golang.org/p/iqOD5hLcPPp

Answer (score 2):

You could also do something like:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

// Test
type stctTest struct {
    blTest *bool
}

func main() {

    strctTest := stctTest{
        blTest: &[]bool{true}[0],
    }

    fmt.Println("Test is " + strconv.FormatBool(*strctTest.blTest))

}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/OWSosQhrUql

Answer (score 0):

Following up on JTs Answer, I also would recommend using the `new` function as such:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

// Test
type stctTest struct {
    blTest *bool
}

func main() {

    strctTest := &stctTest{
        blTest: new(bool),
    }

    *strctTest.blTest = true

    fmt.Println("Test is " + strconv.FormatBool(*strctTest.blTest))
}
```

After initializing the memory with `new()`, you can directly assign a value to the de-referenced pointer. This way you do not need to use another variable to get the address from.

https://go.dev/play/p/BmekoTalQVh